# virtualhost configuration on centos6 vps for a symfony2 project failing with 500 error

Tags: apache, symfony, centos, virtualhost, suphp

I have a VPS running Centos6 (although if my luck so far carries on I might throw it out of the window!).   I am trying to get a small symfony2 project up and running but Im bashing against this error message in the server logs.  There are other non-framework based sites running successfully on the server although non require a vhost.

```
    no user or group set - set suphp_usergroup
```

I have added a virtualhost entry as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName adomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerAlias www.adomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/web

    # I added this after digging around to no avail
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
           suPHP_Engine On
           suPHP_UserGroup username username
   </IfModule>
   ######
    <Directory /home/username/public_html/web>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from ALL
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /home/username/logs/adomain_com.log
    CustomLog /home/username/logs/adomain_com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Ive read through [this](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=apache/CONFIG) and to be honest not a lot makes sense.  suphp is installed on the vps 'out of the box' so I dont have the experience of setting it up.

I would be grateful if someone could help me to debug this error message.

Nearly forgot to say, the application runs sweetly on my home linux dev server.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: why the downvote???? I hate anonymous downvoters.  I welcome feedback, even constructive negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a conflict with cPanel. I'd been going about trying to change the document root all wrong. I didn't need to configure a vhost manually.  In /var/cpanel/user data there's a username folder with a domain configuration file. It was asmall simple as changing it in there, then running /var/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconfig to have cpanel build httpd conf manualy.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the logs in app/logs

Some reasons for this error:

- Error in .htaccess
- Permissions on /web folder are not correct (also check permissions for app/cache/* folder)

More information http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html